# Statement of Theorem in Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples

Tags: integration, probability-theory

The book contains the following theorem in the first chapter of the 4th edition. It's a bit perplexing, because the book doesn't define some terms and notations used here. We assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space. Then we have the following theorem:

> Theorem 1.6.9. Let $X$ be a random element of $(S,\mathcal{S})$ with
>   distribution $\mu$, that is, $\mu(A)=P(X\in A)$. If $f$ is a
>   measurable function from $(S,\mathcal{S})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{R})$, so that $f\geq 0$ or $E|f(x)|<\infty$, then
>
> $$Ef(X) = \int_S f(y)\,\mu(dy)$$

My issue here is that he has previously only used the notation $\int_A f\,d\mu$ in the book. What does it mean when you suddenly put the $d$ inside the measure together with a variable? Having checked carefully the book forgets to define this. The book doesn't define either the meaning of "random element of $(S,\mathcal{S})$" although looking at the proof, it only seems makes sense if the meaning is a measurable map $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\to(S,\mathcal{S})$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, $X$ is a random element of $(S,\mathcal{S})$ means that $X$ is a random variables with values in $S$, i.e. a measurable map from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(S,\mathcal{S})$.

$\int_Sf(y)\mu(dy)$ is the same thing as $\int_Sfd\mu$.It's just another notation that makes clear the variable of integration.